# jscolor with multiple color-pickers visible?

Tags: javascript, colors, picker, jscolor

i'm using the [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) color picker. i need to have multiple pickers visible on the page at the same time. i've tried various permutations of `picker.showPicker()`, but i always get only the last picker displayed. i've verified that the created instances of `new jscolor.color(picker)` are distinct and valid, but can't figure out how to display even 2 different instances simultaneously. anyone have any experience with this package who could give me some insight as to how i could do that?

thanks.

Comment: Are you capable of creating a standalone showcase (jsfiddle or snippet) where this does not work for you? As per the examples this should work just fine.

Comment: sure thing. try [here](http://store3.new-website-online.com/jscolor). you can see that only the 2nd color picker remains visible. if you were to step through in a debugger, you'd see the first one instantiated, then it's cleared or hidden and the 2nd is instantiated.

Comment: Aaah, now I get what you mean. It wasn't clear from your post that you were talking literally about the actual dialog boxes instead of the color pickers in general. I fear however that that indeed is the way jscolor was programmed intentionally (you normally would have multiple input boxes and only show one of those dialog boxes at a time). I *guess* you will have to either fork jscolor or pick another color picker.